# express-session doesn't save any value

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

Before I reload or move to another page, `console.log(req.session)` print exactly what I saved values but It's no longer. I tried req.session.save(), req.session.regenerate({..}) or used .save() and .reload() at the same time. I cannot understand why It happen. I'm struggling with this 6-hours.

app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        maxAge:30 * 60 * 1000,
        expires: 30* 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true
    },
    rolling: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: '~~~~~'
}));
```

routes/index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.test = true;
    req.session.save();
    console.log(req.session);
    res.render('index');
});
router.get('/reg', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session);
    res.render('another');
}
```

When I access 'localhost:3000' the console print like this

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 1800000,
     originalMaxAge: 1800000,
     httpOnly: true },
  test: true }
```

But If I go to 'localhost:3000/reg', It's gone.

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 1800000,
     originalMaxAge: 1800000,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

package ver.

- "express": "~4.13.1",
- "express-session": "^1.14.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#expires), *"The `expires` option should not be set directly; instead only use the `maxAge` option"*.

If you remove the `expires` property, it should work.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I made a same mistake. I always read docs roughly :(